# MVC2 DataAnnotations validation with inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have a .NET 2.0 class the properties of which are marked virtual.I need to use the class as a model in a MVC2 application. So, I have created a .NET 3.5 class inheriting from the .NET 2.0 class and added the DataAnnotations attributes to the overriden properties in the new class. A snippet of what I have done is below

```
// .NET 2.0 class
public class Customer
{
   private string _firstName = "";
   public virtual string FirstName
   {
      get { return _firstName; }
      set { _firstName = value; }
   }
}

// .NET 3.5 class
public class MVCCustomer : Customer
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Firstname is required")]
   public override string FirstName
   {
      get { return base.FirstName; }
      set { base.FirstName = value; }
   }
}
```

I have used the class as the model for a MVC2 view using the HtmlFor helpers. Serverside validation works correctly but the client side validation does not. Specifically the validation error is not displayed on the page.

What am I missing, or is it only possible to do this using buddy classes.

Thanks.

EDIT 1: 
I have now tried this with buddy validation classes and that doesn't work either.

EDIT 2: 
I have now worked out that the lambda expression supplied to the HtmlFor helpers is causing the problem. For e.g.

Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName) calls the ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression method which evaluates the DeclaringType of the MemberExpression (expression.Body) as the Customer class and not the MVCCustomer class.

I have tried changing the lambda expression to Html.TextBoxFor((MVCCustomer m) => m.FirstName) but the DeclaringType is still Customer.

Is there a way I can get the DeclaringType to be of type MVCCustomer and not Customer.

Comment: Did you call EnableClientValidation?

Comment: Yes, EnableClientValidation is called from the aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now got around this by using the new keyword on the properties in the .net 3.5 class as below

```
// .NET 2.0 class
public class Customer { 
  private string _firstName = "";
  public string FirstName
  {
     get { return _firstName; }
     set { _firstName = value; }
  }
}

// .NET 3.5 class
public class MVCCustomer : Customer {
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Firstname is required")]
   public new string FirstName 
   { 
      get { return base.FirstName; } 
      set { base.FirstName = value; }
   }
}
```

This now works as expected and the  DataAnnotations attributes from the MVCCustimer class are applied correctly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but did you include the following scripts in your view/master file?

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These are required for client side validation.

Comment: Yes, I have added the scripts to the master page. To get around this issue I have created .NET 3.5 classes that mirror the .NET 2 classes, applied the DataAnnotations to .NET 3.5 class and copy the properties to the .NET 2 classes using reflection. Not ideal, but it works. I am just surprised as I expected this to work out of the box.